# cookie not setting as expected

Tags: javascript, cookies

When I set a cookie like this, it works:

```
var now = new Date();
now.setDate(now.getDate() + 30);
document.cookie='bla=cats; expires=' + now + ';path=/;'
```

But when I do this it does not:

```
var now = new Date();
now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() + 30); 
document.cookie='bla=cats; expires=' + now + ';path=/;'
```

So I want to set a cookie with 30 mins expiration, not 30 days. 30 days works fine, the latter one does not. Why? How can I set a 30 min cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either try:

```
now.setTime(now.getTime() + (30*60*1000));
```

And/or converting your Date-object into a time-string afterwards, by doing

```
var expires = now.toGMTString();
```

Comment: You might also want to look at .toUTCString() since .toGMTString() is - as I just read - deprecated. It works, but is not encouraged to be used anymore.

Answer (score 1):

this will work:

```
var now = new Date();
now.setTime(now.getTime() + (30 * 60 * 1000));
document.cookie='bla=cats; expires=' + now + ';path=/;'
```

Comment: The now var seems fine but the cookie won't set. I'm testing it out in the Chrome JS console

Comment: @DougFirr works for me... don't forget that the cookie will reside on the stackoverflow.com domain  if you opened the developer tools on this domain.